# C++ array of base class which has instances of derived classes stored in the elements of the array

Tags: c++, arrays, inheritance, base-class

I am creating an application that allows a user to define dimensions for different shapes and returns the area to the user using the dimensions they specified.

My base class is Shape. Derived classes are Triangle, Circle, Square and Rectangle.

I have created an array of Shape in the hope of creating and storing instances of any of the derived classes in the array during runtime.

```
Shape** shape = new Shape*[TOTAL_SHAPES];

shape[i] = new Circle(radius);
```

I have managed this, however I am unable to access the instantiated classes methods. Sorry if this is a stupid question I am fairly new to C++.

Comment: The instantiated methods need to be virtual methods of base class. Otherwise you need to downcast.

Comment: "Unable" how? Explain.

Comment: Please show the class definition and just the area function, either your inheritance or virtual function is likely not defined quite right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume your types had the following definition

```
class Shape {
public:
  void Method1() { ... } 
};

class Circle : public Shape { 
  void Method2() { ... }
}
```

With this definition you could access methods on `Shape` by doing the following

```
shape[i]->Method1();
```

In this context though it wouldn't be possible to access `Method2` though because the compiler only knows about `Shape`, not `Circle`.

```
shape[i]->Method2(); // Error!
```

Comment: Shouldn't Method be virtual?

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum - no it doesn't need to be virtual. You can call any public methods on the base class. If it was virtual then it could be overriden by the derived class in which case the derived class Method would be called.

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum it could be virtual but it does not need to be for this sample to work

Answer (score 1):

You have three options:

1. Make `Shape` an abstract base class and call `virtual` methods that are members of `Shape`
2. Use `static_cast` to cast from a `Shape*` to a `Circle*`, and call methods through that.
3. Use `dynamic_cast` to cast from a `Shape*` to a `Circle*`, and call methods through that.

The first option is likely best in many cases.  Among other reasons, you almost surely need to have a `virtual` destructor (which can be a by-product of making `Shape` an ABC), and you may prefer to not have to know what type of object is being pointed to, rather you'd like to simply call methods on whatever it may be.  If you can use this idiom, use it.

The second option is dangerous.  You must **absolutely know** that the object being pointed to is a `Circle` (or whatever) in order to use `static_cast`, else you will get Undefined Behavior.

The third option is only possible if your class is *polymorphic*, which means `Shape` **must** have at least one `virtual` method.  You surely should have a `virtual` destructor, and this would serve that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

How about that:

```
shape[i]->aMethod();
```

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't seem to work, neither does the dot operator.

Comment: @Mark: Please get into the habit of going further than just saying "it doesn't work". You need to explain, in detail, what happens.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, I highly recommend using a smart pointer wrapper instead of using raw pointers (especially if you are new to the language).

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Shape>> shapes(TOTAL_SHAPES);
```

That will define a vector with an initial size of `TOTAL_SHAPES`.

To the root of your problem, any method you wish to call using a `Shape*` must be valid for `Shape`, or you must do a risky downcast to the appropriate type.  For example:

```
class Shape
{
public:
    // constructors and other methods go here
    virtual ~Shape() { } // virtual destructor

    virtual void Draw() { } // virtual function to be used by derived classes
};

class Circle
{
public:
    // ...
    virtual ~Circle() { }
    virtual void Draw() { } // override the virtual function
};
```

Then, in your application code,

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Shape>> shapes(TOTAL_SHAPES);
shapes[0] = std::make_shared(new Circle);
shapes[0]->Draw(); // calls Circle::Draw
```

Note that depending on your usage, `std::unique_ptr` may replace `std::shared_ptr`.