# How do I initialize an element of an array of superclasses with an instance of a subclass in C++?

Tags: c++, inheritance

Say I have

```
Animal animals[100];
```

And now, at run-time, I want to initialize one of these to be a new instance of `Cat`, a subclass of `Animal`. How do I do this? I thought maybe I could do

```
animals[0] = Cat("Fluffy")
```

but this doesn't seem to work. My understanding of how a constructor works in C++ is that space for the object is allocated, and then a pointer to that space is passed to the constructor function (as `this`). In particular, the constructor works even if that space contains any arbitrary garbage data. So it seems to me that even if `animals[0]` already contains data initialized by the constructor of `Animal` or whatever else was occupying that slot beforehand, it should be possible  to just call the constructor of `Cat` on that space and have it work exactly as if it were a totally "fresh" object. How can I achieve this?

For example, the following code should print "Fluffy", but it prints "Anonymous".

```
#include <stdio.h>

class Animal
{
public:
    virtual char const *get_name() { return "Anonymous"; };
};

class Cat : public Animal
{
    char const *name;
public:
    Cat(char const *name) { this->name = name; }
    char const *get_name() { return name; }
};

Animal animals[100];

int main()
{
    animals[0] = Cat("Fluffy");
    printf("%s\n", animals[0].get_name());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is wrong because `animals[0] = Cat("Fluffy")` calls `Animal::operator=(const Animal&)`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing Generally if you want a heterogeneous array you would need to store _pointers_ to the base class, or preferably a smart pointer, e.g. `std::unique_ptr<Animal> animals[100];`, `animals[0] = std::make_unique<Cat>("Fluffy")`. You could also use something like `std::variant`.

Comment: @jtbandes That seems out of sync with how simple what I'm trying to do seems to be, to me. Why do I need pointers? I *want* my data to be stored sequentially in memory, and for my use case I don't need or want to have to manage allocating and freeing. I don't see why the notion of subclassing should be coupled so tightly with whether you use pointers or direct references.

Comment: Well, subclasses may have different sizes: your Cat object contains a `name` pointer, but Animal does not, so a Cat will not fit in space that was allocated only for an Animal. You will either need indirection provided by a pointer, or some kind of union (ensuring enough space is available; std::variant can do this, or std::aligned_union + placement new for a no-batteries-included approach). If you're storing multiple classes derived from the same base, a union will not allow you to use the common base interface, while a pointer will.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to hear here, that's just the way it is. Imagine `Cat` had more data members than `Animal`. In that case, space for 100 `Animal`s was located but you couldn't fit 100 `Cat`s in there.

Comment: You can check this with `static_assert(sizeof(Cat) > sizeof(Animal))`.

Comment: @jtbandes Oh, okay, I kind of assumed that C++ always treats superclasses as a union over all possible subclasses.

Comment: Questions like this have also been asked several times, although I don't see a great canonical answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20912106/c-array-of-base-class-which-has-instances-of-derived-classes-stored-in-the-ele, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52301418/how-to-add-derived-class-objects-to-an-array-of-base-class-type, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13048301/pointer-to-array-of-base-class-populate-with-derived-class

Comment: That's not possible! What if the base class is implemented in a system library and the derived class is in your program? For example, you might inherit `std::iterator` or `std:: enable_shared_from_this` and your derived class can have as many members as you like.

Comment: C++ brutally abuses folk who dare make assumptions about it. In this case, at the time  `Animal` is compiled say only only `Cat` and `Dog` exist as subclasses. A while later, `Wombat` is added in a third-party library. There's no way for `Animal` to know of this new subclass. Because of this `Animal` only knows `Animal`. All derived classes are unknown.

Comment: Incidentally this is also why virtual destructors are important: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461203/when-to-use-virtual-destructors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is wrong because `animals[0] = Cat("Fluffy")` calls `Animal::operator=(const Animal&)`, which forgets about all the Cat-specific parts of the object. Poor Fluffy has been [sliced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing)

Generally if you want a heterogeneous array, you would need to store an array of **pointers** to the base class, or preferably a smart pointer, e.g.:

```
std::unique_ptr<Animal> animals[100];
animals[0] = std::make_unique<Cat>("Fluffy");
```

You could also use something like std::variant.

This is necessary because subclasses may have different sizes. For example, in your case, Cat contains a `name` pointer, but Animal does not, so a Cat will not fit in space that was allocated only for an Animal. To work around this, you will either need **indirection** provided by a pointer, or some kind of **union** to ensure enough space is available inline. (`std::variant` can do this, or `std::aligned_union` + placement `new` for a no-batteries-included approach).

If you're storing multiple classes derived from the same base, a union will not allow you to use the common base interface, while a pointer will, which is why I'd recommend a pointer here. Remember to give your base class a [virtual destructor](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/384741/28613).

See also:

- [How to add derived class objects to an array of base class type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52301418/how-to-add-derived-class-objects-to-an-array-of-base-class-type)
- [Pointer to array of base class, populate with derived class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13048301/pointer-to-array-of-base-class-populate-with-derived-class)
- [C++ array of base class which has instances of derived classes stored in the elements of the array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20912106/c-array-of-base-class-which-has-instances-of-derived-classes-stored-in-the-ele)

Answer (score 2):

You flat out can't do it the way you're trying to. When you create that array, you allocate exactly enough space to hold 100 Animals. Well, Cats might be a bigger object. There isn't space anymore.

Like some of the other comments, you would need to use a different data structure, probably one that is pointer-based.